# Mapping a Unit Sphere onto $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, stereographic-projections

Q: Place a unit sphere in the $xy$-plane centered at the origin; then draw a line through the North pole $N$ and some point $(x,y,z)$ on the sphere. The line will also cross the $xy$-plane at $(X,Y).$ We thus see that every point (except the North pole) can be mapped to point in $\mathbb R^2.$

Find the mappings between $(x,y,z)$ and $(X,Y).$

I'm not understanding how the formatting of the mappings should be. I am going to use two of these maps to make a smooth structure, create a topology, and then argue it is Hausdorff, but I'm not connecting the dots on what this should look like. A drawing? A set?

Comment: Do you know the coordinates for the north pole?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection

Comment: @ThomasAndrews N = (0,0,1)

Comment: "Place a unit sphere in the xy-plane centered at the origin"

This should be "place a unit sphere in 3d Euclidean space centered at the origin", right?

Comment: You should make your own research. Google it or search for it in YouTube. Stereographic projection of the sphere is something really interesting when you first see it (and not only then). Before doing anything else, try to find it by your own by making a sketch on your paper.